# Detect individual leaves with occlusion

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I am working on automatic weeds and plant system detection and got problems with occlusion - leaves of plants touching each other. Is there another method besides to watershed algorithm , so it can separate them and detect each one individually? Thanks in advance.

**edit:**
Here are the pictures:

occlusion:

http://labs.tineye.com/color/64615cc7415c33fce148e7eb40402698ffc4e294

non-occlusion:

http://labs.tineye.com/color/3181d16239df7b2ceb8899dd9ab69774264ea76b

Comment: I am sorry, I mean occlusion.

Comment: post sample images (best both: images without occlusion and images with occlusion). Tell us what works (sample images of good and bad watershed results). please add those images as single links in full resolution if you can't host images on SO yet. With those images, people might be able to play with some segmentation algorithms for you and might even give working code to you.

Comment: I couldn't post any image because I am a new member in Stackoverflow. So, in order to post images , I need at least 10 reputation.

Comment: I guess you can upload images to other file hosting websites and post links?

Comment: Thank you Micka for this Suggestion,here are the liks:http://labs.tineye.com/color/64615cc7415c33fce148e7eb40402698ffc4e294?ignore_background=True&width=250&color_format=hex&ignore_interior_background=True&height=185

Comment: this one for non occlusion:http://labs.tineye.com/color/3181d16239df7b2ceb8899dd9ab69774264ea76b?ignore_background=True&width=250&color_format=hex&ignore_interior_background=True&height=149

Comment: is your question to segment single leaves (to categorize what kind of plant it is) or to segment single plants (for example to let a robot crop each single plant)? I edited your question to have the links directly there for the reader.

Comment: Actually, I want to discriminate between weed and Cauliflower. Once I segment the cauliflower form the weeds ,so I can be able to draw a box around it.Now,my issue is when the cauliflower grow up till touch another one  (as you can see in posted image ).Segment single plants.